# Javascript audio API: onaudioprocess not fired

Tags: javascript, api, audio, process

I'm building a simple app in which I'm trying to get the buffer, but seems that onaudio process in the following code isn't firing: ([PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/taDngNfK))

```
<script>
var audio_context;
var recorder;
window.onload = function init() {
    try {
        window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
        navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia;
        window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        audio_context = new AudioContext;
        } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
    navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true}, startUserMedia);
    function startUserMedia(stream) {
        console.log('Initializing');
        var input = audio_context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
        input.connect(audio_context.destination);
        var node = input.context.createGain(4096, 2, 2);
        node.onaudioprocess = function(e){
            console.log('done');
        }
        node.connect(audio_context.destination);
    }
};
</script>
```

If the code works as it should I should get `Initiliazing \n done`, the problem is that I'm getting only Initiazing and onaudioprocess isn't fired. I'm using the lastest chrome:

[image]

Comment: Try using `addEventListener` instead of `onaudioprocess`

Comment: Sadly, I couldn't get it working with addEventListener :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`onaudioprocess` is not a property of `GainNode`, but of `ScriptProcessorNode`. See the [API reference here](http://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/#ScriptProcessorNode).

I'm not really experienced with Web Audio API, but if I understood correctly you need to insert it between you gain node and your destination to be able to process those events:

```
var node = input.context.createGain(4096, 2, 2);
var processor = input.context.createScriptProcessor(4096,1,1);

processor.onaudioprocess = function(e){
  console.log('done');
}

node.connect(processor);
processor.connect(audio_context.destination);
```

[Example at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/99rxd/). As you can see, it's printing `done` to the console as the stream is processed, but I can say nothing about the correctness of this setup (since, as I said, little experience) so please double check the connections between nodes - and if necessary adjust the first parameter (the buffer size).

---

**Note:** I'm assuming you want to do something that **alters** the stream (it wasn't clear in your question). If you want to to somehing else (for instance, just analyse it) but won't be changing the input, them you can connect the nodes like you did before (`node` and `destination`) and create the `ScriptProcessorNode` with one input but **no outputs**:

```
var node = input.context.createGain(4096, 2, 2);
node.connect(audio_context.destination);

var processor = input.context.createScriptProcessor(4096,1,0);

processor.onaudioprocess = function(e){
  console.log('done');
}

node.connect(processor);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also bypass the WebAudio event and use Audio's own [`timeupdate`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/embedded-content-0.html#timeupdate) event. It might suit your purpose if you don't need a high-resolution event (such as `audioprocess`).

As opposed to `audioprocess`, `timeupdate` is firing **only when the audio position is changed**: when it is actually playing or you seek to another position. It is said to fire once in approximately 250 ms (so it's low-frequency and thus more performant).

```
function startUserMedia(stream) {
    stream.ontimeupdate = function () {
        console.log(stream.currentTime);
    };
    /* … */
}
```

---

*P.S.*
In your example, you want to `console.log('done')` in the `onaudioprocess` handler. That makes me think that you misunderstand the purpose of the event. It is fired continuously, not once something is done with the stream.